# MongoDB index for finding number between two numbers has high key scan

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing

I have a collection for looking up a user's ASN by their base 10 converted IP address. The schema is as follows:

```
{
    rangeStart: { type: Number },
    rangeEnd: { type: Number },
    asn: { type: Number },
    countryCode: { type: String },
    description: { type: String }
}
```

and the index is:

```
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "rangeStart" : 1,
        "rangeEnd" : -1
    },
    "name" : "rangeStart_1_rangeEnd_-1",
    "ns" : "mydb.asns"
}
```

There are about 450k records in the db, and many of the queries scan 100k+ keys. Sample query below:

```
db.asns.find({ "$and": [ { "rangeStart": { "$lte": 2931838208 } }, { "rangeEnd": { "$gte": 2931838208 } } ] })
```

For the above sample query, execution stats are as follows:

```
{
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "mydb.asns",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "$and" : [
            {
                "rangeStart" : {
                    "$lte" : 2931838208
                }
            },
            {
                "rangeEnd" : {
                    "$gte" : 2931838208
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern" : {
                "rangeStart" : 1,
                "rangeEnd" : -1
            },
            "indexName" : "rangeStart_1_rangeEnd_-1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                "rangeStart" : [ ],
                "rangeEnd" : [ ]
            },
            "isUnique" : false,
            "isSparse" : false,
            "isPartial" : false,
            "indexVersion" : 2,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "indexBounds" : {
                "rangeStart" : [
                    "[-inf.0, 2931838208.0]"
                ],
                "rangeEnd" : [
                    "[inf.0, 2931838208.0]"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
},
"executionStats" : {
    "executionSuccess" : true,
    "nReturned" : 1,
    "executionTimeMillis" : 405,
    "totalKeysExamined" : 244238,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 1,
    "executionStages" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 38,
        "works" : 244238,
        "advanced" : 1,
        "needTime" : 244236,
        "needYield" : 0,
        "saveState" : 1908,
        "restoreState" : 1908,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "docsExamined" : 1,
        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "nReturned" : 1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 37,
            "works" : 244238,
            "advanced" : 1,
            "needTime" : 244236,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 1908,
            "restoreState" : 1908,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "keyPattern" : {
                "rangeStart" : 1,
                "rangeEnd" : -1
            },
            "indexName" : "rangeStart_1_rangeEnd_-1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                "rangeStart" : [ ],
                "rangeEnd" : [ ]
            },
            "isUnique" : false,
            "isSparse" : false,
            "isPartial" : false,
            "indexVersion" : 2,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "indexBounds" : {
                "rangeStart" : [
                    "[-inf.0, 2931838208.0]"
                ],
                "rangeEnd" : [
                    "[inf.0, 2931838208.0]"
                ]
            },
            "keysExamined" : 244238,
            "seeks" : 244237,
            "dupsTested" : 0,
            "dupsDropped" : 0
        }
    }
},
"ok" : 1,
"operationTime" : Timestamp(1598628189, 18)
}
```

Any ideas on how to make this query more performant are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your claimed query and the query plan output have the operators inverted, i.e. the query plan appears to not be for the query you think it is.

Comment: Sorry, I had been trying all permutations of the index/query. Copy pasta mistake. I've updated the question. I actually think this may be a bug from a recent Mongo upgrade

Comment: Your query is not very selective so I'd say the behavior your are seeing is expected.

Comment: Maybe so. I guess I’d expect a similar efficiency to the bisection method when operating on an ordinal index. This query is literally scanning the index one row at a time.

Comment: This query can return every single document in the collection given appropriate boundary. Bisection applies when you are looking for a single document.